# How to remove parent directories from a path

Tags: java

Consider the following code

```
void myMethod(String path) {
    File f = new file("c:\\Temp", path);

    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
}


void myMethodTest() {
    myMethod("..\\elsewhere\\myFile.txt");
}
```

the String printed is `c:\temp\..\elsewhere\myFile.txt`, but what I need is `C:\elsewhere\myFile.txt`.

`File.getCanonicalPath()` won't give me what I want as it will give me the wrong result when `elsewhere` is a sym link

**Updated** I've tweaked the sample code to make my question a little more clear. The second parameter to the File constructor can take any path which may (or may not) contain one of more `"..\"` strings. I want to get a path that has no `..\ elements but does not resolve sym links

**Updated** (Sorry), File `C:\elsewhere\myFile.txt` might not exist (yet)

Answer (score 2):

The `File.getAbsolutePath()` method does not access the FileSystem, hence it will not resolve the eventual symbolic links (nor does the `Path.normalize()` method).

What you want to use is the `Path.toRealPath(LinkOptions... options)`method, which will do the job.

```
void myMethod() {
    File f = new File("c:\\Temp", "..\\elsewhere\\myFile.txt");

    System.out.println(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()).toRealPath());
}
```

Comment: I've just tweaked the question to add one further requirement - the file will not exist (yet). I'm putting together an  application that will download file from a remote server and I'm trying to force the directory they will be stored in,

Comment: How about you using `f.getCanonicalFile().getPath()` ? Would that work ?

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan, No. As stated, getCanonicalFile() resolves symlinks which is something I don't want to do

Comment: @Stormcloud - I did this on OSX. I created a symlink to a directory and then later deleted that directory. My sym link looks like this : `bar -> /Users/kmahadev/foo/` (Here `foo` doesnt exist). I then ran `System.err.println(new File("/Users/kmahadev/work", "../bar").getCanonicalFile().getPath());` If the symlinks were being resolved, I should have seen an error right ? I see the output as : `/Users/kmahadev/bar`

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan may be. but that's not the problem that I'm trying to solve. If I execute File("/myDir", "someFile") i want the result to be /myDir/someFile, even if /myDir is a sym link to somewhere else

Comment: @Stormcloud - I tried that on OSX and it works. `System.err.println(new File("/mydir", "somefile").getCanonicalFile().getPath());` prints `/mydir/somefile`

Comment: According to the JavaDocs getCanonicalFile() involves "resolving symbolic links (on UNIX platforms)", which i do **NOT** want to do (see the original question). It is a requirement that any Sym links in the paths I provide remain unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

`File upDir = new File(f.getParent().getParent(), f.getParent());` -> //parent dir in C:\elsewhere
`File file = new File(upDir, f);` //is gone make file in upDir -> C:\elsewhere\myFile.txt

Comment: Hi @Sławomir Czaja, sorry but this don't work in the general case. It only works in the case that the child path starts with ../ I've updated the question to make this clearer